# Django no encuentra el módulo de GDAL

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Estoy siguiendo este tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/ para crear una aplicacion con geodjango, instalé todos los módulos necesarios, pero parece que django no encuentra el módulo de gdal.

Intalé gdal con pip usando las wheels del repositorio: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal. Y está bajo el mismo directorio que python37: C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\osgeo

Mi version de python es: `Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32` y tengo django instalado a través de pip.

Intenté solucionarlo guiándome por las respuestas a estas preguntas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49139044/geodjango-on-windows-could-not-find-the-gdal-library-oserror-winerror-12

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23197431/geodjango-cant-find-gdal-while-python-can

Así como incluyendo el path de gdal manualmente en el archivo settings del proyecto de Django: `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = 'C:\\Python37\\Lib\\site-packages\\osgeo\\gdal300.dll'`

Pero sin resultado

Este es el error traceback:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .features import DatabaseFeatures
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\features.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.base.features import BaseSpatialFeatures
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\base\features.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models import aggregates
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions  # NOQA
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\functions.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import BaseSpatialField, GeometryField
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\fields.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .fields import (  # NOQA
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\fields.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALException
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\datasource.py", line 39, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\prototypes\ds.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py", line 47, in <module>
    lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado
```

También publiqué la pregunta en inglés:

¿Puede ser un problema con las versiones e gdal y django? También lo intenté con la versión de python2 y tengo el mismo error.

**ACTUALIZACION:**

En un ordenador diferente. He intentado utilizar la versión de GDAL de OSGeoW64.

En este caso mi versión de python es: `Python 3.7.4 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar  25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

Cambiando en settings-py la definición de las variables de entorno (que en realidad ya están definidas):

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    OSGEO4W = r"c:\OSGeo4W64"
    assert os.path.isdir(OSGEO4W), "Directory does not exist: " + OSGEO4W
    os.environ['OSGEO4W_ROOT'] = OSGEO4W
    os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\gdal"
    os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\proj"
```

y me devuelve un error ligeramente distinto:

```
OSError: [WinError 127] No se encontró el proceso especificado
```

Comment: ¿Por qué has instalado las wheels bajadas de un repositorio en lugar de hacer el estándar `pip install gdal`?

Comment: Me daba un error en la instalación: 'Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\
\users\\gacero.ext\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-amwrii\\gdal\\setup.py';f=
getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.
close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\gacero.
ext\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-rfquag\install-record.txt --single-version-ext
ernally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\gacero.ext\appda
ta\local\temp\pip-install-amwrii\gdal\'

Comment: Parece que tu `pip` intentaba instalar para python2.7. Intenta con `python3 -m pip install gdal` ¿Cómo instalaste las diferentes versiones de python que tienes? ¿Has usado algún gestor tipo anaconda, o directamente de la web de python? Si lo instalas vía anaconda, puedes añadirle paquetes (que estén soportados por conda) con un `conda install gdal`. Éste en concreto lo está y la instalación no debería dar ningún problema porque conda usa ya los binarios específicos para tu plataforma.

Comment: Este era el ejemplo al intentar instalar gdal con `pip` en la versión de python2.7. Al intentarlo con la versión de 3.7 devolvía un error similar (al estar ahora en otra máquina no puedo mostrártelo aún), procuré utilizar el `pip` propio de cada versión de python. Instaladas con los ejecutables de https://www.python.org/downloads/. En las variables de entorno solo dejo referenciada la versión de python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente lo resolví instalando una versión anterior de gdal compatible con la versión de django (gdal204 en lugar de gdal300), quitando de las variables de entorno del sistema las referidas a gdal e incluyendo estas en el propio proyecto de Django, en el módulo settings.py:

```
os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = r"C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\data\gdal"
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = r"C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\data\proj"
os.environ['PATH'] = r"C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\osgeo" + os.environ['PATH']
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = r'C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal204.dll'
```

Comment: ¿de dónde instalaste gdal204?